# Calculate distance by road using a series of points

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, google-distancematrix-api

I am  developing an android app wherein I record the points of the device after every 5 minutes.  Now I wish to calculate the total distance covered by road using those points. IS there a way to do that. In google apis I see there is a starting point and and endpoint using which It calculates the distance, but there could be multiple routes for the same. I need to find the distance for this particular route. How do I do that?

Thanks

EDIT:

The google distance matrix api has the options to have multiple origins and multiple destinations . I am not sure If this is of any help :

```
origins — One or more locations to use as the starting point for calculating travel distance and time.
You can supply one or more locations separated by the pipe (|) character, in the form of an address or latitude/longitude coordinates. If you pass an address as a string, the service will geocode the string and convert it to a latitude/longitude coordinate to calculate distances. If you pass coordinates, ensure that no space exists between the latitude and longitude values.
origins=Bobcaygeon+ON|41.43206,-81.38992
Alternatively, you can supply an encoded set of coordinates using the Encoded Polyline Algorithm. This is particularly useful if you have a large number of origin points, because the URL is significantly shorter when using an encoded polyline. Encoded polylines must be prefixed with enc: and followed by a colon (:). For example: origins=enc:gfo}EtohhU:
destinations — One or more locations to use as the finishing point for calculating travel distance and time.
You can supply one or more locations separated by the pipe (|) character, in the form of an address or latitude/longitude coordinates. If you pass an address as a string, the service will geocode the string and convert it to a latitude/longitude coordinate to calculate distances. If you pass coordinates, ensure that no space exists between the latitude and longitude values.
destinations=Darling+Harbour+NSW+Australia|24+Sussex+Drive+Ottawa+ON|Capitola+CA
Alternatively, you can supply an encoded set of coordinates using the Encoded Polyline Algorithm. This is particularly useful if you have a large number of destination points, because the URL is significantly shorter when using an encoded polyline. Encoded polylines must be prefixed with enc: and followed by a colon (:). For example: destinations=enc:gfo}EtohhU:
```

Comment: There are waypoints that you can use for this, along with the starting and end points, or you could use "distance = speed * time" to calculate the total distance. You will have to find the average speed at each 2 points you record, and multiply it by time taken

Comment: @NakulSudhakar "There are waypoints that you can use for this, along with the starting and end points" Can you tell how?

Comment: http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/driving-distance-and-travel-time-duration-between-two-locations-in-google-map-android-api-v2/

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/route-between-two-locations-with-waypoints-in-google-map-android-api-v2/

Please have a look at this.

Comment: @NakulSudhakar Thanks for the link , I went through it. But it again asks for a starting and an end point and then calculates ditance based on 'google's recommended' routes. I need to find the distance for my particular route which might be different from google's suggestion.

Comment: You could specify the waypoints between the start and end points. This way your actual path would be pretty much similar to googles suggested.

Comment: @NakulSudhakar As asked before need to know bit more..what api, what paramter format?

Comment: This solution just uses the google maps url to find the complete path (No APIs), the result of which is a json (as requested in the url) with all the points in between. Now we would have to consider each 2 adjacent points and find the distance between them.
You could first check to see if the result is the same route that you have been taking. If it is, then proceed to find distance between adjacent points. Hope I did not confuse

Comment: Thanks Nakul that was quite informative. I will try it and get back

Comment: // Building the url to the web service
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?"+parameters;

parameters would be 
"origin="+origin.latitude+","+origin.longitude;
waypoints=“+point.latitude + "," + point.longitude + "|"+point2.latitude + "," + point2.longitude + “|”……
"destination="+dest.latitude+","+dest.longitude;


Happy to help

Comment: Keep in mind that tracking vehicles is against the default Google terms. You might want to look into alternative routing software without these restrictions: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing

Comment: Thats interesting can you provide a link to that?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the waypoints of [Google Maps Direction API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Introduction) to indicate the specific road/point that you want to calculate.

You can supply one or more [waypoints](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Waypoints) locations separated by the pipe character (|), in the form of an address, latitude/longitude coordinates, or a place ID.

By default, the Directions service calculates a route through the provided waypoints in their given order. Optionally, you may pass optimize:true as the first argument within the waypoints parameter to allow the Directions service to optimize the provided route by rearranging the waypoints in a more efficient order.

When the Google Maps Directions API returns results, it places them within a (JSON) routes array. Each element of the routes array contains a single result from the specified origin and destination. This route may consist of one or more legs depending on whether any waypoints were specified.

Another way is by using the steps[] in the [legs[]](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#DirectionsResponseElements) field.

Each route within the routes field contains legs[].

`legs[]` - contains an array which contains information about a leg of the route, between two locations within the given route. A separate leg will be present for each waypoint or destination specified.

Each legs field(s) may contain the following fields like

- `distance` indicates the total distance covered by this leg, as a field with the following elements
- `steps[]` contains an array of steps denoting information about each separate step of the leg of the journey

Each element in the steps array defines a single step of the calculated directions. A step is the most atomic unit of a direction's route, containing a single step describing a specific, single instruction on the journey. E.g. "Turn left at W. 4th St." The step not only describes the instruction but also contains distance and duration information relating to how this step relates to the following step. For example, a step denoted as "Merge onto I-80 West" may contain a duration of "37 miles" and "40 minutes," indicating that the next step is 37 miles/40 minutes from this step.

By the use of `steps[]` you can get the specific distance between two waypoints. By adding all of this you will get the total distance.